# Why is hiragana used in the middle of this compound word? (障害者 vs 障がい者)

Tags: kanji, hiragana, orthography

I saw this article on Gizmodo Japan:

> [だれもがスマホの便利さを享受できる第一歩。視覚障**がい**者がiPhone操作を学べるアプリ](http://www.gizmodo.jp/2015/06/iphone_visually_support.html)

Obviously, this is 視覚障**害**者 (or possibly, 視覚障**碍**者).  It is in the title of the article, as well as several places within the body of the article.

Why is the 害 written in hiragana?  Is there some kind of stigma, or political incorrectness behind using 障害者?

Comment: http://www8.cao.go.jp/shougai/suishin/kaikaku/s_kaigi/k_26/pdf/s2.pdf

Comment: http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2138356460935049101

Comment: @YangMuye:  Dang, did you just *happen* to have that handy, or what?

Comment: I just searched "障碍 障がい" on Google, and the second link is that report.

Comment: 害is politically (and historically) incorrect, 碍 is 常用外.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some people argue that the use of "障害者" is politically incorrect, because the kanji "害" has the meaning like "to harm". Because of this, there has been shift to "障がい", especially in media and official documents. It seems [障がい was first seen in 1990s](http://crd.ndl.go.jp/reference/modules/d3ndlcrdentry/index.php?page=ref_view&id=1000117824) on newspapers. On the other hand, some people think that it is oversensitive, and that the mixture of kanji and hiragana is weird. Anyway there has been some arguments over this (try, for example, searching google for [障害+表記+site:go.jp](https://www.google.co.jp/search?&q=%E9%9A%9C%E5%AE%B3+%E8%A1%A8%E8%A8%98+site%3Ago.jp)).

Historically, (as you probably know), 障害 was written as 障碍 or 障礙． Here, "碍" (=礙), as used in [碍子](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A2%8D%E5%AD%90), simply means obstruction, without the negative tones that 害 has. In accordance with the introduction of [常用漢字](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B8%B8%E7%94%A8%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97), which neither 碍 nor 礙 is listed on, those kanji-s were eventually replaced by 害. Because of this, some people (including me, by the way) think that using "障碍" or "障礙" will settle the problem. Newspapers will never use this for now because it isn't listed in the joyo-kanji list, and I don't know if there is any movement towards listing them. It was at least actually discussed in national diet ([question](http://www.shugiin.go.jp/internet/itdb_shitsumon.nsf/html/shitsumon/a167001.htm) and [answer to that](http://www.shugiin.go.jp/internet/itdb_shitsumon.nsf/html/shitsumon/b167001.htm)).

I don't know what ratio of the people think it is (politically incorrect vs not a problem) or (important vs irrelevant vs I don't care).

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps we'll start to see the use of 「がい人」 increase in response to the sensitivity people have over the word「外人」.