# 気をっけて - Why the small っ?

Tags: words, slang, spelling

I'm currently viewing a bunch of tweets about Typhoon Jebi in Kansai, and I'm seeing a lot of people writing 気を[っ]{L}けて specifically with a small っ.

- Is this just some type of stylization?  If so, what kind (internet; young people slang; danger emphasis; etc.)?
- Or is this the case of some special usage like I talk about in this [question about 障がい者](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24810/78)?

Comment: Could you give us some links to these tweets?

Comment: Is this not a typo? It surely seems to me like it's a typo, the kind where the small and normal-size つ don't look very different in size and the user inadvertently chose the wrong one...

Comment: Upon reinspecting them in different browsers, it looks like it may just be a font rendering issue.  If anyone can answer confirming that there is no such stylization or special usage, I'll close this.

Comment: There *is* such a stylization method (see [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%8F%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E6%96%87%E5%8C%96), [this](https://www.j-cast.com/trend/2011/11/11112927.html) and [this](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1468194594)), but it's something that caught on a decade ago...

Comment: @naruto, can you elaborate on that comment in an answer?

Comment: @istrasci Since this is not the case of ギャル文字, I think you can simply close this.